# Splitting the components of a compound verb

Tags: verbs, adverbs, word-order, split

I've always understood that splitting infinitives should be avoided; e.g., instead of

> To boldly go where no man has gone before.

use

> To go boldly where no man has gone before.

With that in mind, I recently saw someone post the following comment on Facebook:

> This is horribly written.

It struck me that a phrasing that sounds more natural to my ear is

> This is written horribly.

In trying to determine why I prefer the latter, I realized that the adverb *horribly* splits the conjugated verb *is written*. Is this just personal preference, or is this "split conjugation" basically the equivalent of a split infinitive?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the so-called 'split infinitive": "To boldly go" is far more natural than "to go boldly", and perfectly grammatical. Inserting the adverb "horribly" between"is" and "written" is not 'splitting the conjugation', as you call it; it's not slitting anything - they are separate constituents. Many adverbs have a lot of freedom when it comes to position. It's a free choice between "is horribly written" and "is written horribly", though I prefer the former. Both are grammatically fine.

Comment: I might also argue that "written" could be considered an _adjective_ in the example sentence given, rather than part of the verb.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these types of 'splitting' are perfectly understandable, and therefore acceptable.  (I just did one.)